# Extract several instances of a sequence from vector

Tags: r

Suppose I have a numeric vector `vec` from which I would like to extract several instances of sequence `seq` that are scattered all over. The sequence's starting indexes in `vec` are known. Ex.:

```
seq <- c(6, 4, 9)
vec <- c(6, 6, 4, 9, 9, 6, 4, 9, 5, 6, 6, 4, 9, 6, 4)
seq_index <- c(2, 6, 11)
```

What I would like to get is someting like this:

```
6, 6, 6
4, 4, 4
9, 9, 9
```

What obviously does not work is:

```
vec[seq_index:seq_index + length(seq) - 1]
```

I also played around with the apply family of functions, e.g.

```
lapply(X = vec, FUN = `[`, cbind(seq_index, seq_index + length(seq) - 1))
```

which also does not yield the expected result.
I am sure I am missing something fundamental here but cannot figure it out.
Any pointers would be highly appreciated.

Comment: shouldn't use `seq` as a name for a vector, given it's a base function in R

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you mean this:

```
sapply(seq_index, function(i) vec[i:(i+length(seq)-1)])
#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]    6    6    6
#[2,]    4    4    4
#[3,]    9    9    9
```

Comment: Grand! I had the vague idea that anonymous functions in conjunction with lapply would be the way to go but have never understood how these work so I assume I avoided to look further into it now. Shame on me! And thanks again.